# Dynamic query in Ibatis with IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, cdata

I wrote a query.It is working with one id.But I wanted that It should work multiple ids so I changed query with `IN($ID$)` but my friend says it is not dynamic.How can I write it dynamically?In second query, I send id with List type.

My query is : (before)

```
<select id="getStudentWithId" parameterClass="map"
    resultClass="com.train.StudentInfo">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT student_id,
               status,                 
               gsm_no
         FROM  student                     
         WHERE student_id= #id#
           AND status = 'SUCCESS'
    ]]>
</select>
```

After Query with 'IN' :

```
<select id="getStudentWithId" parameterClass="map"
    resultClass="com.train.StudentInfo">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT student_id,
               status,                 
               gsm_no
         FROM  student                     
         WHERE student_id IN($id$)
           AND status = 'SUCCESS'
    ]]>
</select>
```

Comment: On what platform do you use this code?

Comment: I use oracle for db